# Gone But Not Forgotten

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, passive-voice, deponent-verbs

On the Andrew Marr TV-prog (Sunday, 10/11/2019) General Sir Nicholas Carter was interviewed. When Marr asked about the declining interest in Remembrance-Day Commemorations, the general quoted Byzantine Emperor, Maurice (late 6thC), who said: "A nation which forgets its defenders will itself be forgotten."

A possible translation could be:

"gens quae eius defensores obliviscitur, memoria ipsius amittetur."

This, not as easy as it first appears; obvious and seemingly only verb for "to forget, "obliviscor" is deponent, prohibiting its use in a passive sense. Therefore, the clumsier alternative: "the memory of itself will be lost".

The court of Emperor Maurice used the Latin language, so this must be written down somewhere. I couldn't find it.

Is this translation correct?

Comment: Maurice wrote in Greek; at least, his famous work on military strategy is in Greek.

Comment: I also doubt that his court principally used Latin, except maybe his law courts.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, Google attributes the quote to Calvin Coolidge rather than the Emperor Maurice.

Anyway I see a couple of issues with your translation: *eius* should be a form of the reflexive *suus*; *obliviscor* takes genitive; and *gens* is a hanging nominative (i.e. it isn't acting as subject of the main clause, since *memoria* is the subject). Fixing these would yield something along the lines of *Gentis quae defensorum suorum obliviscitur memoria amittetur*. If you want to keep *gens* in the nominative, you can do something like *Gens ... memoria excidet*, literally "will fall out of memory". This still doesn't capture the repetition of the verb *forget* which makes the English version rhetorically effective, though; for that, you could maybe start with something like *Gens defensorum immemor* "A nation forgetful of its defenders". Or more pithily, *Oblivio defensorum oblivio populi*: literally, "Forgottenness of defenders [is] forgottenness of the people".

Answer (score 0):

Oblita populi sui gens obliscenda est.

Going for minimalism, this translation means:

A nation forgetful of its (own) people must/is right to/should/ought to/is right to be forgotten.

Comment: Think it's "obliviscenda"; "oblita" = "having forgotten". The essence, here, is the soldiers/ warriors/ defendors; "defensores" cannot be omitted.