# How can we say "a forgotten war" in Latin?

Tags: deponent-verbs

How can we say "a forgotten war" in Latin?

You know what I'm really getting at: I'm asking "[How to make a deponent passive in meaning?"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4658/118) but with a specific and puzzling example. *[Oblīvīscor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obliviscor#Latin)*, "I forget", is a deponent verb, so *oblītus* can only mean "so-and-so having forgotten [something]".

Didn't the Romans ever feel the need for a past participle to express the idea of having been forgotten, generally, without specifying who forgot? Did no Roman grammarian ever curse this gap in the language?

Answer (score 7):

The poets seem to have noticed this gap, and repurposed *oblītus* to fill it. So saith Vergil himself (*Eclogues* IX.53-4):

> nunc **oblita** mihi tot carmina, vox quoque Moerim / jam fugit ipsa
> *Now all my songs have been **forgotten**, and even my voice itself now abandons me.*

Comment: Hmm, doesn't this mean "Now I have forgotten all my songs?" But _oblita_ does modify _carmina_! "Now, so many songs forgotten to me, the voice too flees Moeris." Hey, Moeris is talking about himself in the first person and the third person in the same sentence! I see that L&S marks this with "!*?" This is indeed good evidence that the Romans felt my pain.

Comment: @BenKovitz I took the !*? to be marking the Plautus attestation, since the Plautus manuscripts are known for having many idiosyncrasies. But indeed; I'm not sure why Moeris uses his name there, but I suspect the meter had something to do with it.

Comment: @Ben Kovitz You're right. This is an adjectival/resultative passive with a so-called (miscalled!) "dative of agent". Verbal/eventive passives are different. The translation you've given is correct (NB: the resultative construction is more literally rendered as: 'I have all my songs forgotten'). Verbal passives typically express agents with a by-phrase: 'all songs have been/were forgotten by me'. Is this possible in Classical Latin? I don't think so.

Comment: @Ben Kovitz: In Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/12836/1982, I had this problem, dealt with by TKR: passive, "will be forgotten", became "will fall out of memory" = "memoria excidet".

Comment: @Draconis Oops, indeed they marked Plautus. I guess I was stunned by L&S's punctuational extravagance.

Comment: @Mitomino [Quaestionem novam](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/16680/118) proponi aliquando oblituram…mm, oblitteraturam?…obliviscendam? Sententiam tuam de passivum resultativum audiendi studiosus sum.

Comment: @tony That might be a winning answer!

Comment: @tony Wait, I just found a problem with _excidere_. I'll post it as answer myself right now.

Comment: @Mitomino "Datives of agent" aren't uncommon with finite verb forms in poetry, either: Aeneid I.440 _cernitur ulli_ "is perceived by anyone".

Comment: The example _cernitur ulli_ is the typical one found in Latin grammars but is not as common as one could think (please see Section 5 of this paper: http://www.unioviedo.es/pmsuarez/Articulos_files/Le%20datif%20agent.pdf ). In any case, what is important here is to realize that the example in your answer is better understood as an adjectival/resultative passive rather than as a verbal passive (cf. _nunc_). Perhaps I didn't express myself clearly above: a clear(er) example of verbal passive with _obliviscor_ would be one having a by-phrase. As noted, I don't think this exists in Classical Latin.

Comment: @Mitomino Sententia tua de passivo resultativo dativoque auctoris nunc intellecta mihi fieri incipit. Proponas responsum in quaestione nova? Tum eam pertractam omnibus scribere potueris.

Answer (score 4):

Hic renovabo illud, quod ad [interrogatum pristinum](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14884/14886#14886) respondi, propositum persimplex:

> bellum oblitteratum

Vocabulum «oblittero» infrequentissime dicitur litterate, immo solum fere tropice utitur praesertim Livius historicus, quam ob rem arbitror id idoneum esse, quod ad verbum «bellum» adiciatur.

Comment: plerumque vero non oblitteratum est bellum, sed oblitterator. :)

Comment: @d_e Si quando agens neutrius est generis, *oblitteratrum* appellari potest. ([Hic tractata sunt nomina agentium omnium generum](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/178/79).)

Answer (score 1):

[Tony](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/1982/tony) referred to [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/13021/118) by [TKR](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/40/tkr), which has this phrase:

> memoriā excidet
>
> It will fall out of memory.

I like the metaphor. [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dexcido1) document a sense of simply "to slip from memory" for *excidere.* But there's a problem: *excidere* has no passive participle, indeed no passive forms at all. How was anyone able to communicate in this language??

(P.S. I had never before noticed that "fallen" is an active past participle in English.)